# Error al compilar en nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express

Estoy aprendiendo nodejs y tengo expres 4.X, uso ejs y html

```
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set ('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Luego en html añadi esta ruta para que salga la barra de menu que tengo en otra ruta, pero me salta un error

```
<%- include partials/navigation.html %>
```

Probé también `<%`, `<%=` y nada

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in 
C:\RUTA\src\views\index.html while compiling ejs
If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
```

Navigation.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><%= title %></a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
         aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
         <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
             <li class="nav-item active">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>contact</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo

Comment: Puedes poner el código que tienes en partials/navigation?

Comment: Por supuesto, listo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el error, era un error de sintaxis, la manera actual es esta:

`<%- include('partials/navigation.html') %>`

Gracias pipe igualmente